# How to validate if at least one column is unique in laravel excel

Tags: excel, laravel

I am using laravel Excel to import data from an excel file into the database.

```
public function rules(): array
{
    return [
        'brand_name' => [
            'required',
            'string',  
            'unique:medications,brandName'
        ],
        'company_name' => [
            'required',
            'string',  
            'unique:medications,companyName'
        ],
        'type' => [
            'required',
            'string',  
            'unique:medications,type'
        ],
        'category' => [
            'required',
            'string',  
            'unique:medications,category'
        ],
    ];
}
```

The problem is that I want to validate all the columns and check if at least one of them have different data when compared to data from the database. Basically, if I add a new data that are similar data from the database with similar data for most columns except for at least one, it will still add it into the database. Right now, I can only add data if all column are unique

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way could be not to use the row validation of the Laravel Excel, but at the model function where you import your data, before return your model, you can use a custom query to validate if at least one of them have different data and depending the result you can save the current row or not.

I don't know if you can somehow concatenate all columns and use the result of the concatenation at rules function, I mean to specify unique constraint for multiple columns, but if it is ok for you, you can add this constraint for all columns  at the DB and skip errors (in case of duplicate) at laravel Excel.